# split text in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to split text in stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
(
     @ArrayList nvarchar(1000)
)
BEGIN

     --I want to split @ArrayList. That is contains string. ex '1,2,3,4,5,6...'

END
```

Comment: stuff like that **should** be reflected in the tags you choose! Just "stored-procedures" isn't very helpful..... Also: which **version** of SQL Server??

Comment: Also: something like this has been asked a gazillion times already - you should **SEARCH FIRST** before asking YET AGAIN - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432623/sql-server-2005-function-split-string-into-decimals or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866168/sql-split-function-that-handles-string-with-delimeter-appearing-between-text-qual or see the whole list here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+split+text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @ArrayList nvarchar(1000) = '1,2,3,4,5,6'

declare @XMLList xml
set @XMLList = cast('<I>'+replace(@ArrayList, ',', '</I><I>')+'</I>' as xml)
select 
  I.value('.', 'int') as Value
from @XMLList.nodes('I') as I(I)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use should use `XML PATH` method as below :

```
SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT TOP 10 ',' + STOCKNO FROM ItemMaster FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
) as Data
```

Result:

```
Data
150200006,150200010,150200014,150200018,150200021,150200025,150400078,150400082,150200005,150200009
```